# For loop counting between numbers

Tags: c, for-loop

What is the problem with the code? It always return me the B value. I'm trying to count the numbers between two values. Thanks in advance!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main(void) {

      int a, b, i, cont;

      printf("Digite um valor de Inicio: ");
      scanf("%d", &a);

       printf("Digite um valor de Fim: ");
       scanf("%d", &b);

       for(i=a;i<b;i++);


       printf("Existem %d numeros entre os valores fornecidos", i);

    system("pause")
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C the following is the syntax of `for` loop.

```
for ( init expression; condition expression; update expression) {
   statement(s);
}
```

Note that, you can have multiple statements separated by `,` in each expression of the for loop.

To answer your question, you need to do,

```
for ( <initialize i with zero, initialize count to zero>; 
      <check to break the loop, it is already correct>; 
      <increment i, increment count>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to update cont when for loop execute i.e calculate numbers between two values. And then print the cont.
**Easy way**: use b - a equation instead of loop.

Comment: My teacher wants a for loop to be used :(( and how do i update cont? Srry im a begginer

Answer (score 0):

**Set the counter:**

```
if(!a < b){
    printf("Numbers should be not equal");
    return;
    }
int count=0;
for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
count=count-1;
printf(i);
```